# Passing IOptions<T> to method in StartUp Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, appsettings

I have set up my project to use the `IOptions` pattern for reading data from the `appSettings` file.

I have a class that has the following simple constructor to it:

```
public PlayClass(IOptions<MySettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings;
}
```

In my `ConfigureServices` method I have my config set up here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(options));
}
```

When I run or test this, everything works as expected. However, I need to call a method from my play `PlayClass` inside of `ConfigureServices`.

What is best way to achieve this?

I had originally thought it would be as simple as the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    var x = services.Configure<BitBucketSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("BitBucketOptions").Bind(options));

    var pc = new PlayClass(x);
    pc.MyMethod();

}
```

But this only results in an error: `cannot convert from IServiceCollection to IOptions<MySettings>`

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new class object, indeed you can inject it right?

Comment: You can inject and resolve `PlayClass`

Comment: @user1672994 Is there an example you can point me to? First time being exposed to this

Comment: @N0xus you can try this way. servies.AddScoped<Interface,Implementation>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you want to create an object of class in `Startup` class. But you can solve your problem as following.

IServiceCollection is used only for create the dependency graph but to resolve the actual dependencies at runtime, `ServiceProvider` is needed.

To build ServiceProvider, `BuildServiceProvider` method needs to be called on ServiceCollection. You can see that in the code below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    //Register the configuration section in the service collection.
    services.Configure<BitBucketSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("BitBucketOptions"));

    // Register the class in service collection.
    services.AddScoped<PlayClass, PlayClass>();

    // Build Service Provider
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // Resolve instance or PlayClass from service builder.
    var pc = sp.GetService<PlayClass>();

    //  Call method on instance of PlayClass
    pc.MyMethod();
}
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.